# Wanted to display the total cost of vacation including a percentage, but instead displays 0

Tags: java

I wanted to display the total cost of the vacation including a percentage, but it displays zero instead.
I'm just starting to learn oop, but this assignment made me hesitate about learning programming. I hope for your understanding!
I think it's about the formula in the account class.Either it's because of the wrong getters and setters. When I call season_num it shows 0 although it should have called 4,3,2 or 1 as it was in the setter

```
Main class
package com.company;
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PriceCalculator pc= new PriceCalculator("summer","vip",5,50.25);
    pc.displayAccount();
}
}

//Another class

package com.company;


public class PriceCalculator {
private int numberOfDays;
private double pricePerDay;
private String season;
private String typeDiscount;
private int season_num;
private int discount;
private double result;

PriceCalculator(String season, String typeDiscount, int numberOfDays, double pricePerDay){

    this.numberOfDays=numberOfDays;
    this.pricePerDay=pricePerDay;
    this.season=season;
    this.typeDiscount=typeDiscount;
}


String getSeason(){
    return this.season;
}
void setSeason(String season){
    if(season.equals("summer")){
        season_num=4;
    }
    else if(season.equals("winter")){
        season_num=3;
    }
    else if(season.equals("spring")){
        season_num=2;
    }
    else if(season.equals("autumn")){
        season_num=1;
    }
}

String getTypeDiscount(){
    return this.typeDiscount;
}
void setTypeDiscount(String typeDiscount){
    if(typeDiscount.equals("vip")){
        discount=20;
    }
    else if(typeDiscount.equals("secondvisit")){
        discount=10;
    }
}

int getNumberOfDays(){
    return this.numberOfDays;
}
void setNumberOfDays(int numberOfDays){
    this.numberOfDays=numberOfDays;
}

double getPricePerDay(){
    return this.pricePerDay;
}
void setPricePerDay(double pricePerDay){
    this.pricePerDay=pricePerDay;
}

double getResult(){
    return this.result;
}
void setResult(double result){
    this.result=result;
}


void displayAccount() {
    class Account {
        void displayAccountInfo() {
            double res = pricePerDay * season_num * numberOfDays;
            result= res-(res/discount);
            System.out.println(result);
        }

    }

    Account a= new Account();
    a.displayAccountInfo();
}
}
```

Comment: You are net calling `setSeason` anywhere in your code, so `season_num` will always be `0`.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your constructor. You are not applying the setters with the custom logic you implemented. Try the following in your `PriceCalculator` class instead of the current constructor you have:

```java
PriceCalculator(String season, String typeDiscount, int numberOfDays, double pricePerDay){
    this.numberOfDays = numberOfDays;
    this.pricePerDay = pricePerDay;
    setSeason(season);
    setTypeDiscount(typeDiscount);
}
```

Comment: What do I need to learn to understand OOP, can you recommend books?

Comment: I would go with "Head First Java" and "Head First Object-Oriented Analysis and Design" after that one. Did my answer solved your issue?